# Make a table showing the 10 largest values of a variable in R?

Tags: r, subset, tabular, r-table

I want to make a simple table that showcases the largest 10 values for a given variable in my dataset, as well as 4 other variables for each observation, so basically a small subset of my data. It would look something like this:

```
Score  District  Age  Group  Gender
17     B         23    Red   1
12     A         61    Red   0
11.7   A         18    Blue  0
10     B         18    Red   0
.
.
etc.
```

whereby the data is ordered on the Score var. All the data is contained within the same dataframe.

Comment: Is it grouped by Var4?  What is the expected output

Comment: hi @akrun, the expected output is pretty much what I've written in the box, just with 10 rows instead of 4. Var1 could be something like a test score, and var2-var5 would be demographic data, e.g. var2=district, var3=age, var4=class, var5=sex

Comment: It is better to show that also because description can be confusing.  Sorry, I didn't understand what you wanted.

Comment: Updated the variable names

Comment: Do you want the 10 largest rows based on the `Score`, grouped by 'Group'

Comment: I basically just want the 10 largest values for score in the dataset, and include the other 4 variables for reference. No grouping variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it...

`data <- data[with(data,order(-Score)),]`

`data <- data[1:10,]`

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Thanks so much. It seems that brackets in R do much the same that the replace command does in Stata.

Comment: Maybe you could just wrap it into `head(data[order(-data$Score),], 10)`

Answer (score 19):

You can do this using `arrange` from `dplyr`.  This should also work if there are grouping variables.  Just add `group_by` before the `arrange`.  We filter the first 10 observations using `slice`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
    arrange(desc(Score)) %>%
    slice(1:10)
```

Or another option is `?top_n` (commented by @docendodiscimus) from `dplyr` which is a wrapper that uses `filter` and `min_rank` to select the top n (i.e. 10) entries for 'Score'.

```
 top_n(df1, 10, Score)
```

Or we use `filter` by creating a logical condition with `row_number` which is equivalent to `rank(ties.method='first')` (contributed by @Steven Beaupre)

```
 filter(df1, row_number(desc(Score)) <= 10)
```

Or a data.table option (by @David Arenburg).  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` (decreasing) the 'Score' variable, and select the first 10 observations.  `.SD` means `Subset of DataTable`.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[order(-Score), .SD[1:10]]
```

Comment: Or `top_n(df1, 10, Score)`

Comment: `top_n` uses `min_rank` and `rank(ties.method = "min")`. If you want to have the results with `ties.method = "first"` you could do: `filter(df1, row_number(desc(Score)) <= 10)`

Comment: I wonder if you also could add `setDT(df1)[order(-Score), .SD[1:10]]` or `head(setDT(df1)[order(-Score)], 10)`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the highest values of a vector using the code below:

```
my_vec <- c(1:100)
tail(sort(my_vec),10)
```

So if you want to use this method as a data frame filter you could do:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars[mtcars$mpg %in% tail(sort(mtcars$mpg),4),]
```

which would produce:

```
> mtcars[mtcars$mpg %in% tail(sort(mtcars$mpg),4),]
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 2):

From `dplyr` >= 1.0.0, we can use `slice_max` function.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% slice_max(mpg, n = 4)

#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

By default rows with ties are selected, if you want to ignore ties and strictly return `n` rows use `with_ties = FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM mtcars 
      ORDER BY mpg DESC 
      LIMIT 10", row.names = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```