# Subset a dataset to leave the largest 2 values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set:

```
col1 col2 

A     3
A     3
B     2
C     1
B     2
A     3
D     5
B     2
D     5
B     2
F     0
F     0
A     3
C     1
C     1
```

How can I subset it so as to "leave" the top 2 col1 values. So my output is this:

```
col1 col2 

A     3
A     3
A     3
D     5
A     3
```

I have viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939643/make-a-table-showing-the-10-largest-values-of-a-variable-in-r), but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: *"subset it so as to "leave" the top 2 col1 values"* is confusing me. Do you mean "keep the rows that have the top 2 `col2` values?"

Comment: @GregorThomas yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but not sure why you only have one `D`:

```
#Code
newdf <- df[df$col2 %in% sort(unique(df$col2),decreasing = T)[1:2],]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your data is in a `data.frame`.

First of all, you need to get the top 2 values of `col2`. Therefore you can take the unique values of it, sort them in decreasing order, and take the first two elements:

```
col2Values <- unique(df$col2)
top2Elements <- sort(col2Values,decreasing = TRUE)[c(1,2)]
```

Now you know the top2 values, so you just need to check where these values appear in `col2`. This can be done via:

```
df[df$col2 %in% top2Elements,]
```

Update: Now it should work, I had some typos in there.